# What is the command to replace [x] with [x+5] in vim

Tags: vim

What is the command to replace a number in [] with number+4 in brackets?
e.g. [4] => [8]

```
:%s/\[\(\d\+\)\]/\=submatch(1)+4/Ic
```

I figured out till this part, but cannot get the [] appear after replacement.

Ideas?

Comment: make a macro that searches to it and then does `4+Ctrl+a`

Answer (score 4):

Substitution's sub-replace-expression expects a string.

```
:%s/\[\(\d\+\)\]/\='['.(submatch(1)+4).']'/Ic
```

Alternatively use `\zs` and `\ze` to set the start and end of the match so you do not need to add back the square braces.

```
:%s/\[\zs\(\d\+\)\ze\]/\=submatch(1)+4/Ic
```

For more help see:

```
:h sub-replace-expression
:h String
:h expr-.
:h /\zs
```